# Push value from Observable<Object> into Observable<Array>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have two different API endpoints. One returns a `Cards` object, the other an Array of `Cards` objects. What I want to do is get the first Card as the first element in the Array from the second endpoint. Is there any way to do that? Both are observables returned from `HTTPClient`, so maybe it would be simple to do with some operator, but I don't know enough to do that yet. Just to illustrate it better:

**I have:**

```
latestCards$: Observable<Cards> = http.get('latestCardsEndpoint');
// { title: 'Latest', cards: [], ... }  

featuredCards$: Observable<Cards[]> = http.get('featuredCardsEndpoint');
// [
//   { title: 'Featured1', cards: [], ... }, 
//   { title: 'Featured2', cards: [], ... },
//   ...
// ]
```

**I need**

```
homeCards$: Observable<Cards[]>;
// [
//   { title: 'Latest', cards: [], ... },
//   { title: 'Featured1', cards: [], ... },
//   { title: 'Featured2', cards: [], ... },
//   ...
// ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

Naive approach:

```
import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

homeCards$= forkJoin(latestCards$,featuredCards$).pipe(
  map(([latest,feature]=>[latest,...feature])
);
```

This has one limitation: waits for both requests to be completed to emit the first value, which is the complete list.

Naive approach 2:

```
import {combineLatest} from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

homeCards$= combineLatest(latestCards$,featuredCards$).pipe(
  map(([latest,feature]=>[latest,...feature])
);
```

Same limitation as before, only that it waits for both streams to emit at least once. Because these are http observables, they only emit once (response) and then complete. So its the same.

A better approach:

Assuming that the latestCard$ request takes less time to respond, use it as first result while fetching the rest of the data on the background.

```
import {merge} from 'rxjs/observable/merge';
import {of} from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import {mergeMap, map}from'rxjs/operators';

homeCards$= latestCards$.mergeMap(latest => {
            const fullResult$ = featuredCards$.map(featured => [latest,...featured]);
            return merge(of([latest]), fullResult$);
            });
```

Comment: Thanks. While both the 2 'naive' approaches - and also @Boris's answer - work better for my specific project, your answer was really good and helped me realize some other aspects of working with observables and operators.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to solve this, one would be this:

```
Observable
    .combineLatest(latestCards$, featuredCards$) // return an array of responses
    .map(([lastestCard, featuredCards]) => [lastestCard, ...featuredCards])
    .subscribe(// do your stuff)
```

Here's an example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/foxfghhn/